# Parallel stream doesn't set Thread.contextClassLoader after tomcat upgrade

Tags: java, java-stream, tomcat8, forkjoinpool, contextclassloader

After tomcat upgrade from 8.5.6 to 8.5.28 parallel stream stopped supplying Threads with contextClassLoader:

Because of it `Warmer::run` can't load classes in it.

```
warmers.parallelStream().forEach(Warmer::run);
```

Do you have any ideas what Tomcat was supplying for contextClassLoaders for new Threads?

ParallelStream uses ForkJoinPool in newest Tomcat.

Comment: what is the symptom of `Warmer::run`'s inability to load classes?

Comment: Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() returns null @diginoise

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Common ForkJoin pool** is problematic and could be responsible for memory leaks and for applications being able to load classes and resources from other contexts/applications (potential security leak if your tomcat is multi tenant). See this [Tomcat Bugzilla Report](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60620).

In [Tomcat 8.5.11](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/changelog.html) they had applied fix to the above issues by introducing [`SafeForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory.java`](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/tc8.5.x/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/startup/SafeForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory.java?view=markup)

In order for your code to work, you can do the following, which will supply explicit **ForkJoin** and its **worker thread factory** to the `Stream.parallel()` execution.

```
ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(NO_OF_WORKERS);
forkJoinPool.execute(() -> warmers.parallelStream().forEach(Warmer::run));
```

Comment: Fantastic!  This made us solve a really hard-to-debug problem we had with Apache Abdera and JDK10.

Answer (score 8):

This saved my day! 
I had to do it like this to make it work:

```
private static class CustomForkJoinWorkerThread extends ForkJoinWorkerThread {
    CustomForkJoinWorkerThread(ForkJoinPool pool) {
        super(pool);
        setContextClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    }
}

private ForkJoinPool createForkJoinPool() {
    return new ForkJoinPool(
            ForkJoinPool.getCommonPoolParallelism(),
            CustomForkJoinWorkerThread::new,
            null,
            false
    );
}


createForkJoinPool().submit(() -> stuff.parallelStream().doStuff())
```