# Is SpringBoot 2.4.2 ResourceLoader thread safe?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java.util.concurrent

Here is the bean

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BeanWithResourceLoader{
    private final ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    @SneakyThrows
    private String readResource() {
        return IOUtils.toString(
          resourceLoader.getResource(
            "classpath:/some_resource.json").getInputStream(), 
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    } 
}
```

Another bean calls it:

```java
        var result =
                customThreadPool.submit(
                () -> listOfThings.parallelStream().map(aThing ->beanWithResourceLoader.readResource())
   .collect(Collectors.toList()))
   .get();
```

`customThreadPool.submit` or just `listOfThings.parallelStream()` causes java.io.FileNotFoundException at `readResource` It can't find file!

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [some_resource.json] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180)
```

but `stream` (no concurrency)

```java
listOfThings.stream().map(aThing ->beanWithResourceLoader.readResource())
   .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

works...

Un-reproducible in unit-tests, reproducible when application is started as jar.

How can I overcome it?

Comment: I assume it's thread save, since you're performing read-only operations. I've checked this code and got no exceptions. I think, you need to check whether this file is in classpath of jar.

Comment: You may be suffering from contextClassLoader. There is an example; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49110537/parallel-stream-doesnt-set-thread-contextclassloader-after-tomcat-upgrade